# Ошибка "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" при сборке в MinGW

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, mingw

Сразу скажу - я нуб в C++, но хочется его изучить.
Пытаюсь скомпилировать вот этот код:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
// Register the window class.
const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);

// Create the window.

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Test programm",               // Window text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
    );

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

// Run the message loop.

MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Для удобства компилирования я сделал маленький скрипт:

```
@set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
@gcc main.cpp
@pause
```

При попытке компилирования мне выводит это:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
 collect2.exe: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

Как код не выглядел, всё равно не хочет компилироваться. Что делаеть?

Comment: Visual C++ скомпилировал, пустое окошко выкинул.

Comment: @Harry `Сразу скажу - я нуб в C++, но хочется его изучить.`

Comment: Ну, я бы все же советовал бы начать с консольных программ.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы использовать юникодный `wWinMain()`, добавьте флаг [`-municode`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps) (при линковке чтобы убрать ошибку, и при компиляции чтобы автоматически задефайнить `UNICODE`).

---

Это работает только в MinGW-w64.

Старый [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (не -w64) не поддерживает юникодную версию `WinMain`, поэтому надо использовать неюникодную версию:

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
```

а параметры командной строки получать через `GetCommandLineW()`:

```
int argc;
wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    //output argv[i]
}
```

Взято отсюда: [WinMain compiles, but wWinMain does not in CodeBlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418188/winmain-compiles-but-wwinmain-does-not-in-codeblocks)

Comment: а [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11706847/1654293) говорят, что для новых версий поддержка есть, да и для старых есть враппер на github

Comment: @mega Спасибо за ссылку. И да, там речь про MinGW-w64, а не про новые версии MinGW (который до сих пор ничего такого не умеет). Добавил уточнение в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная проблема решилась тем, что файл в VS Code просто был сохранен перед компиляцией.
Вынужден признать, это ошибка новичка (меня). Надеюсь 30 минут времени, проведенные в изучении работы WinMain тоже не были потрачены зря.

Answer (score -1):

Переустановка была необязательна. `С++` нормально компилируется с объявлением

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

А вот с Си что-то не то... Конечно, выход простой - переименовать `main.c` в `main.cpp`, тогда будет использоваться `g++` вместо `gcc`. Но это же не выход!

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Каким-то чудом оно заработало, переустановив MinGW и все пакеты. А также использование G++ вместо GCC. 
Но мне пришлось сделать код очень простым, выводя диалог "hello world".
Спасибо кто пытался мне помочь)

Comment: Что значит "заработало"? На картинке вы собираете совсем другой исходник. Он бы и так собрался, без переустановки.